# Java instantiating child object from parent object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a following class that shares the same "state" and performs CRUD actions. This operation is not repeatable/idempotent.

```java
public class Client {
    private static String state;
    public Client(args){
        this.state = buildStateFromArgs();  // this value will not change
    }

    public void createUser();
    public User getUser();
    public User updateUser();
    public void deleteUser();

    public void createJob();
    public Job getJob();
    public Job updateJob();
    public void deleteJob();

    // other CRUD functions ....
}
```

I am thinking of refactoring it to something like

```java
public class Client {
    public Client(args){
        this.state = buildStateFromArgs();
    }
    private static String state;
}

public class UserClient extends Client{
    public void createUser();
    public User getUser();
    public User updateUser();
    public void deleteUser();
}
```

But I am not sure what is the best approach to instatiate the child class. Suppose this is the current implementation,

```java
Client client = new Client(args);
client.createUser();
client.createJob();
```

Should I simply just downcast?

```java
Client client = new Client(args);
UserClient userClient = (UserClient) client;
userClient.createUser();
JobClient jobClient = (JobClient) client;
jobClient.createJob();
```

Or should I construct the child from parent?

```java
Client client = new Client(args);
UserClient userClient = new UserClient(client);
userClient.createUser();
JobClient jobClient = new JobClient(client);
jobClient.createJob();
```

Or is there a better design pattern suited for this kind of problem?

Comment: Why don't you call `super(args)` from your `UserClient` constructor?

Comment: JobClient extends Client or UserClient?

Comment: `Composition` is always preferred over `Inheritance` in cases like this.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I forgot to mention in my question that I cannot create the "state" parameter twice (it will be different every time buildStateFromArgs is called) and this value has to be shared across child instances

Comment: @everton, all the child classes will extend Client.

Comment: @WaiYan Please update your question to reflect that state is `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `UserClient` *is-a* `Client`, I would take the following approach:

```
UserClient client = new UserClient();
client.createUser();
```

My reason for taking this approach is that user-specific functions should only exist on a `UserClient` and can therefore only be called from such.

Given the new information that the `state` must be shared across all clients, I'd probably use a static initializer:

```
class Client {
    private static String state;
    static {
        state = buildStateFromArgs(args);  // this value will not change
    }
}
```

This assumes that the `args` are available this point. If they are not, then you need to make `buildStateFromArgs()` a `public`, `static` function and call it before any sub-classes are instantiated:

```
Client.buildStateFromArgs(args);
UserClient client = new UserClient();
...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I cannot create the "state" parameter twice (it will be different every time buildStateFromArgs is called) and this value has to be shared across child instances.

Comment: @WaiYan OK, I've updated my answer to reflect that state is `static`, ie. shared.

Comment: one more question if you don't mind, is this approach thread-safe?

Comment: I would think so. The only caveat is you need to ensure the `state` is set _before_ any thread creates a client (and potentially uses that `state`).